# Using files that have spaces in their name in pipes

Tags: shell, find, pipe, tar, whitespace

I have folder named `play` which contains a file `damn file` (with space). When I use `find` and pipe the output to `tar`:

```
find play/ -name 'damn*' | tar cf archive.tar -T -
```

It works perfectly. Why does this works The output of `find` contains space that should cause problem for `tar`. When I use this command:

```
tar cf archive.tar $(find play/ -name 'damn*')
```

bash shows these errors:

```
tar: play/damn: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: file: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

I'm confused. Why does the first example work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the second example, the newlines are removed by the shell, which does word-splitting on the output of the command substitution.  Since newlines are included in `IFS` by default, they are treated as field delimiters and not as part of the fields themselves.  In the first example, the input is coming from a pipe and not the shell so the shell can't do word-splitting.

Double quoting the command substitution (`"$(find ... )"`) will prevent word splitting from taking place, but `find` inside command substitution is almost always a *bad* idea so don't do that.  For maximum safety, whenever you have access to the GNU versions of Unix tools you should use the null-delimiter options:

```
find dir/ -name '...' -print0 | tar cf foo.tar --null --no-recursion -T -
```

Answer (score 4):

`find play/ -name 'damn*'` will produce a list of filenames, 1 per line.  If `play/damn file` is the only matching file, then it's equivalent to `echo 'play/damn file'`.

Tar's [`-T` option](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/files.html) expects filenames to be separated by newlines.  Any other whitespace is considered part of the filename.  That's why your first example works.

When you use [`$(...)`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html), the output of the command is [split on whitespace](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html) by the shell, and then each word becomes a parameter to `tar`.  Thus, `play/damn` and `file` become two arguments, and neither one is an existing file.